# oh-my-zsh update gives error fatal invalid reference: master

Tags: oh-my-zsh

On startup, oh-my-zsh suggests an update. But pressing Y gives the following error:

```
fatal: invalid reference: master
```

Tried:

```
cd ${ZSH}; git status; git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** Master branch changed its name to main, but upgrade scripts still try to use master.

**Solution:** Run the following command to update

```
sed -i 's/master/main/' ${ZSH}/tools/upgrade.sh ${ZSH}/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh
```